# Mmapping shared memory in C giving Invalid argument error when I change the offset to anything nonzero

Tags: c, unix, posix, mmap, execl

I'm trying to open a shared memory file, write in it, fork to new processes, then call execl to run other components, then in those components I want to access the shared memory created in the parent. But I dont want the entire structure, only part of it. So I use offsetof to find the offset and pass that into mmap. Problem is, it gives an Invalid argument error when I change the offset to anything other than zero. It works fine with zero.

I've made a minimal dummy program with the same error, and the code for the larger program is too big.
`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/mman.h>
#include<stddef.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

typedef struct test
{
    int moo;
    char hello;
}Lil;


typedef struct bigstruct
{
    int a;
    char cow;
    Lil lil;
}Big;

int main()
{
    int fd = shm_open("/moomor", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        perror("shmopen");
        return 1;
    }
    ftruncate(fd, sizeof(Big));
    Big * big = (Big *)mmap(NULL, sizeof(Big), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if(big == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        perror("mmap");
        return 1;
    }
    big->lil.hello = 'h';
    printf("hello: %c\n", big->lil.hello); //prints correctly
    munmap(big, sizeof(Big)); //tried it with this in and out

    int offset = offsetof(Big, lil); //gives offset of eight
    printf("Offset: %d\n", offset);
    Lil *lily = (Lil *)mmap(NULL, sizeof(Lil), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, offset);
    if(lily == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        perror("mmap"); //this causes an error
        goto cleanup;
    }
    printf("HH: %c\n", lily->hello);
    munmap(lily, sizeof(Lil));

    cleanup:
    shm_unlink("/moomor");
    close(fd);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using a Linux-based platform, the manual page for the function [`mmap`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) states the following:

> offset must be a multiple of the page size as returned by sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE).

It appears that you are violating this rule in your posted code.

Comment: Thank you so much! I agree that seems to be the problem, to get around this I assume I'd get the offsetof the struct I want. Then find the nearest page alignment multiple and pass the remainder into the child process get a void pointer to that particular page and then use the offset to get the specific struct?

Comment: @entonces: Finding the "nearest" page alignment multiple seems wrong to me. I rather guess that you would want to find "the next lower" page alignment multiple, so that the mapped memory range contains all the data that you want. Also, it is possible that the data may span multiple pages, so I don't think you will want to work with "particular pages".

Comment: Yes next lower is what I meant sorry. If the data spans multiple pages that shouldn't be an issue right? I've implemented it and it works though so far, thank you.

Comment: @entonces: Yes, it should not be an issue. My point was that working with a single page may not be sufficient. For example, if the data happens to be on a page boundary, then it may span multiple pages, even if the size of the data is significantly smaller than a page.